# Cutting a triangle out of square

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a shape of a triangle cutting a square.

I tried using this code but it doesnt create the shape I want.

```css
.square-cut{
  font-size: 0px; line-height: 0%; width: 0px;
  border-top: 20px solid purple;
  border-bottom: 20px solid purple;
  border-right: 40px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="square-cut"></div>
```

The shape I want is this:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How's this (comments in code):

```css
/* make arrow as after pseudo element*/
.square-cut:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  line-height: 0%;
  font-size: 0px;
  background: purple;
  border-top: 20px solid purple;
  border-bottom: 20px solid purple;
  border-left: 40px solid white;
}
.square-cut {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50px; /* as arrow is 40px x 40px, this gives 10px under the tip*/
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px 0; /* 5px on either side offat side of the arrow */
  background: purple;
  font-size: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="square-cut"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Exactly what I was looking for